# How to use ValueMapper to change value type in Kafka Streams 10.2 using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am attempting to upgrade my Scala based Kafka Streams app from 0.10.0.0 to 0.10.2.1 and I can not figure out how to get the app to compile.

The example I found in the [documentation](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.2.x/kafka-streams/src/main/scala/io/confluent/examples/streams/MapFunctionScalaExample.scala) uses `mapValue` but it does not change the values type. I am using Scala 2.11 with the `-Xexperimental` compiler flag as per [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.2.x/kafka-streams#requirements-scala).

**Code**

```
class MyStream() {
  def startMyStream(): Unit = {
    val kStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder
    val kStream = kStreamBuilder.stream("myTopic")

    kStream.mapValues(new ValueMapper[AnyRef, Double]() {
      override def apply(value: Any) = 6.3
    })

    val kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(kStreamBuilder,  new Properties)
    kafkaStreams.start()
  }
}
```

**Compiler Error**

```
no type parameters for method mapValues: (x$1: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[_, _ <: VR])org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream[Nothing,VR] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[AnyRef,Double]{})
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
  found   : org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[AnyRef,Double]
  required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[_, _ <: ?VR]
Note: AnyRef <: Any, but Java-defined trait ValueMapper is invariant in type V.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
    kStream.mapValues(new ValueMapper[AnyRef, Double]() {
            ^
type mismatch;
  found   : org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[AnyRef,Double]{}
  required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[_, _ <: VR]
    kStream.mapValues(new ValueMapper[AnyRef, Double]() {
                      ^
two errors found
```

Expressed as a java class this compiles fine.

```
public class MyStream {
    public void startMyStream() {
        KStreamBuilder kStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder();
        KStream kStream = kStreamBuilder.stream("myTopic");

        kStream.mapValues(new ValueMapper<Object, Double>() {
            @Override
            public Double apply(Object value) {
                return 6.3;
            }
        });

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(kStreamBuilder, new Properties());
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }
}
```

How do i get the Scala version to compile?

---

**Solution based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44732478/444639)**

Three ways that work and two that do not.

```
class MyStream() {
  def startMyStream(): Unit = {
    val kStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder

    // Explicit tying here is not required to compile and run. 
    val kStream: KStream[Array[Byte], String] = kStreamBuilder.stream("myTopic")

    // Does not compile
    kStream.mapValues(new ValueMapper[AnyRef, Double]() {
      override def apply(value: AnyRef) = 6.3
    })

    // Does not compile
    kStream.mapValues(_ => 6.3)

    // Works
    kStream.mapValues[Double](new ValueMapper[AnyRef, Double]() {
      override def apply(value: AnyRef) = 6.3
    })

    // Works, requires compiler option -Xexperimental
    kStream.mapValues[Double](_ => 6.3)

    // Works, requires compiler option -Xexperimental
    kStream.mapValues[Double](convert)
    def convert(string: String): Double = 6.3

    val kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(kStreamBuilder, new Properties)
    kafkaStreams.start()
  }
}
```

---

**Update: solutions that did not work**

**Attempt 1** Adding explicit types to the kStream as suggested (`val kStream: KStream[Array[Byte], String] = kStreamBuilder.stream("myTopic")`) still does not compile and results in this error.

```
no type parameters for method mapValues: (x$1: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[_ >: String, _ <: VR])org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream[Array[Byte],VR] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[AnyRef,Double]{})
--- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
  found   : org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[AnyRef,Double]
  required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[_ >: String, _ <: ?VR]
Note: AnyRef <: Any, but Java-defined trait ValueMapper is invariant in type V.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
kStream.mapValues(new ValueMapper[AnyRef, Double]() {
  ^
  type mismatch;
  found   : org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[AnyRef,Double]{}
  required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[_ >: String, _ <: VR]
  kStream.mapValues(new ValueMapper[AnyRef, Double]() {
```

**Attempt 2** Adding the above and using SAM conversions to "to avoid explicitly writing out an instantiation of an anonymous class" (`kStream.mapValues(_ => 6.3)`) resulted in this compiler error.

```
no type parameters for method mapValues: (x$1: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[_ >: String, _ <: VR])org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream[Array[Byte],VR] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[String,Double] with Serializable)
--- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
  found   : org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[String,Double] with Serializable
  required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[_ >: String, _ <: ?VR]
Note: String <: Any (and org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[String,Double] with Serializable <: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[String,Double]), but Java-defined trait ValueMapper is invariant in type V.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
kStream.mapValues(_ => 6.3)
        ^
type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[String,Double] with Serializable
required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper[_ >: String, _ <: VR]
kStream.mapValues(_ => 6.3)
                    ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, you do not specify the type of the stream:

```
val kStream: KStream[Array[Byte], String] = kStreamBuilder.stream("myTopic")
```

This is actually the cause of the error you see - since you don't specify the types, Scala infers them to some defaults, which is almost always not what you want.

Second, since you had enabled `-Xexperimental`, you can rely on SAM conversions to avoid explicitly writing out an instantiation of an anonymous class:

```
kStream.mapValues(_ => 6.3)
```

**Update:** it seems that for some reason Scala compiler is unable to properly infer the output type of the anonymous function/SAM instance here. I was able to compile the code successfully with the following small tweak:

```
kStream.mapValues[Double](_ => 6.3)
```

Comment: What Vladimir said.  Also, this problem is covered in the Kafka Streams FAQ at http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#scala-compile-error-no-type-parameter-java-defined-trait-is-invariant-in-type-t.

Comment: Both of these solutions still result in compiler errors.

Comment: @MikeRylander apparently it is necessary to explicitly specify the output type in the `mapValues` signature. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I found that I did not need the explicit typing on the KStream, just needed it on the `mapValues` call.